# How to sync data between users ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to know if there is a way to have data be linked between different users. In my case I'm building a gift wish list and each item has a buy button attached to it. if the buy button is clicked and someone buys the item then the item no longer needs to be displayed. but i have no idea how sync that data between users. I tried using sqlite but I wasn't able to find a way to store the data that is returned from `db.each` since its asynchronous. I also thought of JSON but there didn't seem to be a good way to write to an external JSON file. I know that I can't be the only one with this issue but I don't really know what to search in order to find the answers I'm looking for.

TIA

Comment: Try websockets.

Comment: May be https://socket.io/ is what you are looking for.

Comment: Whenever the user clicks on buy button, you make a backend api call and update th item quantity and return the response. if you are capable of updating i.e, qtyAvailable>=quantityOrdered, then update the user view accordingly, if you are not capable of updating i.e, qtyAvailable<quantityOrdered then  disable the buy button or provide the necessary info to the user.
Using websockets complicates the system and difficult to maintain for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Three approaches I would suggest. (The problem isn't really tied to ReactJS)

**1. Reactive Approach**

- Let the buy button buy and update the record accordingly in the backend denoting that it is sold.
- Any succeeding requests for that backend will result in an error.
- Up to you how you will do the UX, but usually a pop up saying the item is now sold out is enough. (This is when you can remove the said
  item from the view.)
- This is far the easiest to implement in my opinion.
- This is a classic solution to a race problem.

**2. Real Time Approach**

- there are many solutions you can use to do this. I won't deep dive on what solutions you can use. But basically, you need to find a way to have an open connection between your data source and frontend enabling real time subscription (like Facebook notifications or messaging)
- One solution is to use sockets as one of the comment dictates. Basically, when a request to the backend was made, there should be an event that would trigger a push to all subscribed frontends that this item was bought. (You can then do the necessary frontend UX after receiving such event.)
- You will still need to do the reactive solution just in case.
- This is hard to implement since your number one problem is to support scale and possibly an event driven architecture.

**3. Near Real Time Approach**

- Not really elegant, but you can just poll for changes in the backend in the background and when something was updated you can do the necessary UX.
- Still need to do the reactive solution.
- Be careful though on the interval though, it might mimic a DDoS attack but nothing a cache can't solve if it's just pure GET requests.

Comment: Option 1  seems like the best idea imo. whats your recommendation for a backend? I've never really done full stack so I have no idea what would work well in this scenario. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I would suggest to use a framework like NextJS so you can do serverless apis out of the box and deploy to Vercel without the hassle of using an actual backend framework. This is by far my recommended way for you so you can kick the gears fast.